# Ubutntu: How to install Mysql Server 4.1.22 or 4.1.21 on Clound

Tags: command-line, mysql, webserver

We have POS software which requires only mysql server version 4.1.22 and 4.1.21. Am using Hetzner cloud and i try many solutions and cant found way how to install this specific version!

Does anyone have suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! MySQL server 4.1.22 is from November 2006. In computer terms, this is considered an antiquity. 1) Unfortunately, this community will not be able to offer support for running deprecated versions of software. 2) You should perhaps consider running important applications on supported software. 3) In any case, the most (and IMO only) viable option for running deprecated software is through Docker or a VM.

Comment: It will be very difficult to install that version of MySQL on any modern OS. There are some unsupported Docker containers available with that version, but none from well-known, trusted sources. You may want to look at ways to implement a newer version of MySQL for the POS system or look at building a translation layer that will operate between the POSes and the database server.

Comment: "We have POS software which requires only mysql server version 4.1.22"  That means your Ubuntu is also end-of-life. Best advice: update your software if you have things specific to v4.1 But I doubt there is. You should be able to use 5.6?!?! "Hetzner cloud" generally you need to use a new instance with new versions of all software.

Comment: That is not my software! We buy it from local company and thay not want to change it